# How to bind razor variable to vue attribute?

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, razor

I am trying bind a razor variable to html attribute with vuejs.

The variable which i must use is "@culture". It is a string variable which gives me current culture information.

My code is:

```
<div class="dropdown-product-item" v-for="(item, index) in card.items">
<span class="dropdown-product-remove"><i class="icon-cross" v-bind:data-id="item.Id" v-on:click="removeFromCard"></i></span>
<a class="dropdown-product-thumb" v-bind:href="/@{Html.Raw(culture);}/item.Link">
    <img v-bind:src="item.ResimUrl" v-bind:alt="item.Ad">
</a>
<div class="dropdown-product-info">
    <a class="dropdown-product-title" v-bind:href="/@{Html.Raw(culture);}/item.Link">{{item.Ad}}</a>
    <span class="dropdown-product-details" v-if="!item.IndirimliFiyat">{{pieces[index]}} x {{item.Fiyat.PriceString}}</span>
    <span class="dropdown-product-details" v-else>{{pieces[index]}} x {{item.IndirimliFiyat.PriceString}}</span>
</div>
```

This code doesn't work. I only see white screen.

How to I do this? Could you help me?

Comment: Doesn't simply `@culture` work, as in `v-bind:href="/@culture/item.Link"`?

Comment: I tried it before. It doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me if I have something like `<div data-dummy="/@culture/item.Link">`, it should work in your case too. Are you sure you have a value in `@culture`, can you try displaying it on the page in a span like `<span>@culture</span>`?

Comment: I used it for normal html attributes but i cannot for vue.js attributes. I think cause of this is virtual dom management of vue.js. But i don't know solving this issue.

Comment: @cinarizasyon did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do something similar